# C# Dataset Firebird DB Trigger Timestamp

Tags: c#, triggers, dataset, timestamp, firebird

We have a firebird db, with the corresponding typed datasets in c#.

id columns have the auotincrement property. when we insert a new row the 
tableadapter automatically retrievs the new id.

On some tables we have a timestamp, which gets updated before update statements
with a trigger on the db.

Is there a easy or automatic way to keep the dataset in sync with the database ? 
I know the method with getchanges and applychanges. 
But isn't there an simpler way of handling such columns ?